# Wordpress use the same URL to display different content eg for seasonal websites

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, conditional-statements, href

I'm looking to create a summer and winter version of a site.

Some content eg. products are unique to the season. Other content such as the contact page is universal.

The menu/footer is different for each season. I can set up a conditional menu so that it shows for certain pages/taxonomies etc. but how would that work for pages that are universal?

example: https://www.whistlerblackcomb.com/about-us/contact-us

You can see they are using the same contact page with the same URL but with a season-specific menu and slightly different content (hero image) depending on if the user has clicked on the "summer" or "winter" switch (top right).

How is this achieved?

I thought a nice way to do this could be in the same way hreflang works but I'd have no idea how to do that outside of languages.

Answer (score 0):

They set a cookie (if you are in chrome, open up the developer tools, click on Application > Cookies > https://www.whistlerblackcomb.com, and you will see an entry "season" which changes when you click on that switch).  On the server, they check the cookie, and then vary the response based on its value.

Comment: Cheers Dave, I'm not sure how to implement the different responses within a wordpress environment but will look further into this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a simple function in your functions.php to check the current month:

```
<?php
function is_winter(){
    $month = date('m');
    if($month > 10 || $month < 3){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Then use anywhere on your site like:

```
<?php
if(is_winter()){
    //It's Winter
}else{
    //It's NOT Winter
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not sure how this would work with displaying certain page builder modules or menu etc. If you could wrap a module, the header etc. with the if else statements, that could work! Is this possible?

Comment: You could have 2 separate header files header.php and header-summer.php then if(is_winter()){get_header();}else{get_header('summer');} or if you just wanted one header file you could have 2 menus, I'm not sure how you are calling your menus in but if you were using wp_nav_menu($args); you could have if(is_winter()){$args = $winter_args}else{$args = $summer_args}. You could use this function you add a css class like if(is_winter()){echo 'winter-class'} for styling. You can use it multiple times and wrap anything you like in it.

Comment: ok, yes, that makes sense... and would it then be possible for the visitor to click a "summer" button if it's during the winter months and it would display the summer header (and whatever else you have versions of)?

Comment: I'm sure it could be done, not sure how your summer pages are set up but maybe overwrite the is_winter() function by passing in a false parameter or a query string at the end of your URL ?winter=false there's a few ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the direction Paul, I'm going to study up on a few things and start testing.